# Prove the following mapping is a determinant of order $n$: $D_{n}(A)=\sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{i+j}a_{ij}D_{n-1} (A_{ij})$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand a proof for the following:

> Prove the mapping defined by $$ D_{n}(A)=\sum_{j=1}^n
>  (-1)^{i+j}a_{ij}D_{n-1} (A_{ij}) $$ is a determinant of order $n$. The
> following is a copy of the proof:

$\textbf{Proof}:$
Denote $D_{n-1}$ by $D$. Assume $A=[a_{ik}]_{n \times n}$. Let $A'$ and $B$ be the matrices by replacing its $k$-th column with

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a'_{1k} \\
\vdots \\
a'_{ik} \\
\vdots \\
a'_{nk}
\end{bmatrix}
\hspace{5mm}\text{and} \hspace{5mm}
\begin{bmatrix}
sa_{1k}+ta'_{1k} \\
\vdots \\
sa_{ik}+ta'_{ik} \\
\vdots \\
sa_{nk} + ta'_{nk}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
respectively. Plainly, $B_{ik}=A_{ik}=A'_{ik}$ and $b_{ik}=sa_{ik}+ta'_{ik}$. If $j\neq k$, then $b_{ij}=a_{ij}=a'_{ij}$. In this case, we also have $D(B_{ij})=sD(A_{ij})+tD(A'_{ij})$ since $D$ is supposed to satisfy the definition of the determinant.

The proof then goes on, but I would say I understand the rest of it (if I assume $B_{ik}=A_{ik}=A'_{ik}$ to be true).

My question is, how can $B_{ik}=A_{ik}=A'_{ik}$, and what even are those terms? In my interpretation, $B_{ik}$ represents the value in $i$th row of and $k$th matrix $B$, From this understanding, we would have $a_{ik}=a'_{ik}=sa_{ik}+ta'_{ik}$ which is obviously not the case. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have a reference to a source (book, etc.) where this proof occurs? It's difficult to follow some of the language and notation in your post.

Comment: @blargoner sadly it's my own professors book (which he gave out as a pdf on the introductory meeting) and I'm not sure if I'm allowed to distribute it. There is no other way to get hold of the book sadly.

Comment: It seems $B_{ik}$ is obtained from $B$ by removing the $i$-th row and the $k$-th column. The same for $A_{ik}$ and $A_{ik}'.$ The equality is then obvious, as the $k$-th column is removed  from all three matrices.